# Black screen when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have draw a view inside my storyboard that have 300x350 pixels, I want to present this view inside my current view (600x600 pixels and is a initial view controller), for this I try this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ModalViewController *viewController = (ModalViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalView"];

viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{
    viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 350);
    viewController.view.superview.center = self.backgroundColorView.center;
}];
```

This code have two problems:

1. My view load in full screen and have a delay that changes the screen size to 300x350 pixels.
2. Outside of my view I can see a black screen (In my case was supposed to appear the part of my other view).

How can I solve this problem? (I'm not using navigation controller)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change modalPresentationStyle to be overCurrentContex